# Continue counting when Index parameter is set to a value

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have made an each loop which counts a number of posts, using an index parameter.

I want to set that index param to a certain value and then it counts from there.

But when I do set it to a value in the loop, it doesn't continue counting, it just outputs that assigned value for the number of objects in the loop.

I have attached snippets below and a screenshot of the console.log result.

CODE -

```js
    $.each(articleArray[0], function(i) {
        i = postID;
        slideCount++;
        console.log(i++);
        articleContent = articleArray[(pageNumber - 1)][i].content;
        $('.swiper-slide:nth-child(' + slideCount + ')').html(articleContent);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Console Screen]

Comment: Where does `postID` come from? Is that where you want to *start*?

Comment: Yes, so the postID comes from a data value when you click on a post. So say its just set to 1, then set i to 1 and then continue counting from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the index parameter. Use your own variable you create *outside* the `$.each` loop:

```
var counter = postID;
$.each(articleArray[0], function() {
    slideCount++;
    articleContent = articleArray[(pageNumber - 1)][counter++].content;
    $('.swiper-slide:nth-child(' + slideCount + ')').html(articleContent);
});
```

Note that I moved where the increment on it was, from the `console.log` (which I assume is temporary) to the actual use of it. If you **meant** it to start out at `postID + 1` (which is what incrementing it in the `console.log` did), just add the `+ 1` to the first line defining `counter`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, will mark it correct when Stack allows me. I appreciate the help.